# From android keycodes to java keycodes

Tags: java, android, sockets, keyboard

Hi im developing a remote keyboard app that controls computer's keyboard from android device.

But the problem is when i want to pass android keypresses keycodes to use in java's Robot class the alphabets and numbers works great but the backspace and shift key for example doesn't work properly. When i press it from android it displays 22 on my computer.

This is my code on android

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) 
{
    int keyaction = event.getAction();

    if(keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        int keyunicode = event.getUnicodeChar();
        char character = (char) keyunicode;

        PrintStream ps;
        try {
            ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ps.println(character);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

And this is the code on computer

```
public class Keyboard extends Thread{
    InputStreamReader isr;
    BufferedReader br;
    Socket socket;
    Robot r;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = SocketWrapper.getSocket();
            r = new Robot();
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        if(socket != null)
                        {
                            try {
                                isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                                if(br.ready())
                                {
                                    char c = (char) br.read();
                                    System.out.print(c);


                                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.getKeyCodeForChar(c));
                                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.getKeyCodeForChar(c));


                                }
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(AndroidServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }

            }).start();
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Keyboard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getKeyCode` instead of `getUnicodeChar` because the second one gets the Unicode **character** generated by the specified key and meta key state combination. Shift is a meta key and it doesn't generate any character code itself.
On the other hand the `getKeyCode` method retrieves the **key** code of the key event.

Of course you need to modify receiving part of your code to treat these codes as keys and not characters.

Comment: does getKeyCode return ascii or some other values? cuz i tried but nothing happens

Comment: kecodes are not ascii (that are character numbers actually), but codes for keyboard events that include media keys, hardware keys, metakeys such as backspace and shift that you mentioned, and of course ordinary letters. These codes just need to be converted aappropriately on the PC into characters (if you really want to get character) or better analyse what type of code you receice (char or control symbol).

Comment: When you do `System.out.print(c);`, you might extect the character to be printed, but the system output is unable to print backspace. Try to print the code number instead of the character. I'm sure you'll get different values for different keys. To better understand how it all works, consider installing KeyEvent display - it prints out every key event that the application receives.

Comment: For example, the following output output was generated for sequentiol pesses of letters Q, Z, backspace, shift (only relevant codes are left due to limitation of comments and sorry cant enter linefeeds):
    KeyDown: code=45  meta=0 scancode=0 label='Q'
    KeyUp: code=45  meta=0 scancode=0 label='Q'
    KeyDown: code=54  meta=0 scancode=0 label='Z'
    KeyUp:  code=54  meta=0 scancode=0 label='Z'
    KeyDown: code=67  meta=0 scancode=0 label=''
    KeyUp:  code=67  meta=0 scancode=0 label=''
    KeyDown: code=59  meta=64 scancode=0 label=''
    KeyUp: code=59  meta=0 scancode=0 label=''

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation, so is there anyway to convert keycodes to ascii or something that java's robot will recognize

Comment: @Tomahawk, sorry, I don't understand how you want `Shift` key to be converted into ascii? If you want it to be ptinted as "Shift" then look for key code 59 and print "Shift"

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to send the virtual key code for SHIFT, BACKSPACE and other keys where event.getUnicodeChar() is undefined;

```
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT)
         keyunicode = 16; //this is the code for KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT;
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
         keyunicode = 8;  //this is the code for KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE;
    ....
```